# Dropdown not updating with updated data in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am facing the problem with select options in Rails. While changing the state, the city options should be appended but it's not working for me. Please help me, what did wrong in that

This what I did:
          In my _form.html.erb file:

```
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <!-- State -->
          <%= label_tag "Shop address" %>
          <%= select_tag :pstate, options_for_select(CS.states(:in).map { |c| [c[1], c[0]] }), class: "form-control", :required => true, :onchange => "stateChanged(event)" %>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <!-- City -->
          <%= label_tag "Shop location" %>
          <%= select_tag :pcity, options_for_select([@pcities]), class: "form-control", :required => true %>
        </div>    
      </div>  

    <script>
       var stateChanged = function(e){
       $.ajax({
         url: "products/product_cities?state=" + e.target.value,
         type: "GET"
       })
     }
   </script>
```

And in products_controller.rb file

```
   def product_cities
         @pcities = CS.get(:in, params[:state])
         puts @pcities.inspect
       end
```

And in products_cities.js.erb file

```
    <%# // Find the state select box %>
 var city = document.getElementById("pcity");
 console.log(city);
 <%# // Clear the options in the select box %>
 while (city.firstChild) city.removeChild(city.firstChild);

 <%# // Add a placeholder %>
 var placeholder = document.createElement("option");
 placeholder.text = "Choose a city";
 placeholder.value = "";
 city.appendChild(placeholder);

 <%# // Add the cities %>
 <% @pcities.each do |c| %>
     city.options[city.options.length] = new Option('<%= c %>');
 <% end %>
```

Could you please help me to get out of this.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
...options_for_select([@pcities])...
```

Into this (don't forget to do it to both lines!):

```
...options_for_select([@pcities],@<<PUT YOUR MODEL HERE w/o BRACKETS>>.pcity)...
```

What this optional last argument does is set the selected value of the dropdown IF it exists. Quite handy.

This is an example of my own using all the arguments of the select helper:

```
<%= f.select :state, options_for_select(us_states, @user.state), {:include_blank => "Select a state"}, {:class => "form-control"} %>
```

The `:include_blank` is essentially a placeholder. Hope this helps!